# How to go to next line by pressing space at end of the current line in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

My textarea is setup with these two relevant style attributes:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The functionality that i am trying to achieve is that when the user presses the space button enough times to reach the right edge of the textarea I want the cursor to move to the next line.

Comment: how can one go to the next line if already on the last line? lines come from returns.

Comment: It's a weird behavior of textarea in chrome (maybe other browsers too).. you can't wrap to next line by typing spaces when you're at the end of line. Not sure why anyone would want that tho, it sounds pretty dumb.

Comment: If you want to go to the next line, why not pressing `[enter]`? I am just trying to understand the requirements and limitations

Comment: What would be the application of something like this?

Comment: I changed the wording on my question to make it less ambiguous davis, and Mighty I want this behavior because I am creating a special text box that needs to do what the user wants and this behavior just seems necessary.

Comment: Yes enter already works, but I want to achieve this certain behavior using the space key as well at the end of lines.

Comment: Well I suppose you could try some hack with JS, catching the key events... another approach is to ditch textarea and try contenteditable.

Comment: it's doable for sure. are all the other "lines" hard-coded, or are you using a set width and a fixed-width font and can assume that every say 50 chars equates to a new line?

Comment: Just tested it and div with contenteditable works great for this. It won't work in form tho, you'll have to extract the text yourself by js.

Comment: Interesting... I have never heard of content editable and this seems to meet the required specifications of my textbox. Thanks for the great find!

Answer (score 0):

I did the "hack with JS" ... it's quite simple:

```js
var keypress = function(event){
  var textarea = event.target;
  var content = textarea.value;
  var cols = textarea.cols + 1;
  if(content.length % cols === textarea.cols){ textarea.value += '\n'; }
}, textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for(var t = 0; t < textareas.length; t += 1){
  var textarea = textareas[t];
  textarea.addEventListener('keyup', keypress);
  textarea.addEventListener('keydown', keypress);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
```